# Angular 5 Webpack Compiled successfully but home page is not loading

Tags: angular, angular5

I have setup angular project locally in my system. When I run command `ng serve --open` then I am getting message that webpack compiled successfully but in the browser I am getting error

> This site can’t be reached localhost took too long to respond. Search Google for localhost 4200 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I don't understand how do I debug the issue.

**Edit:**
Here is the screenshot of the screen which i am getting

[image]

**EDIT 2 **
I run command `ng test` and now i am gettiing

> ERROR in
>   src/app/global-notifications/global-notifications.directive.spec.ts(5,23):
>   error TS2554: Expected 6 arguments, but got 0.
>   src/app/request.service.spec.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module './request.service'.

Comment: please show error msg in console you get

Comment: I am not getting any error in console.

Comment: its showing a blank page or something

Comment: it seems, your application is not running.. have you changed default port number anytime before?

Comment: @harkeshkumar i updated above with the screen i am getting.

Comment: @codeninja.sj No I didn't changed port number. I have 2 machines and in my previous machine the project was working fine. Today I setup the same project on another machine then its not loading in browser.

Comment: update project and then like ( npm install, ng update , then ng serve

Comment: I tried `ng update` command and getting error of  `Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found`

Comment: @devtester you are getting the angular.json error because you haven't done `npm install`

Comment: Yes, after few minutes i found that i didn't run `npm install` command. After that i got the new error that i updated above. Can you please look at it and suggest me way to get it fixed.